# Python's PyQtGraph: Is it possible to have a gradient-filled plot?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

Is it possible to generate a plot that looks like this using PyQtGraph?I know how to create a filled plot, but I can't find any examples of applying a gradient to the filled region.

[image: Gradient filled plot example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into brush and setfilllevel on the [PlotCurveItem](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotcurveitem.html). You can set the brush with a gradient from PyQt.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()

grad = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 3)
grad.setColorAt(0.1, pg.mkColor('#000000'))
grad.setColorAt(0.9, pg.mkColor('b'))
brush = QtGui.QBrush(grad)

p = win.addPlot(y=3+np.random.normal(size=50), brush=brush, fillLevel=0)

import sys
if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```